# Set the PinEntryEditText limit programmatically

Tags: android, github, android-edittext

I'm using [this](https://github.com/alphamu/PinEntryEditText) library in my app. I have to set the limit of the edittext programatically.
Right now I'm doing it in xml file `android:maxLength="5"` .But I want to set it differently for different activities and the length will be decided dynamically ., How can I achieve it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is method available `setMaxLength()` in source code of `PinEntryEditText` to set MaxLength

[check line number 116](https://github.com/alphamu/PinEntryEditText/blob/e8e11ae5aca77d56103fd6ba6f8c04b539031f63/pinentryedittext/src/main/java/com/alimuzaffar/lib/pin/PinEntryEditText.java#L116)

```
public void setMaxLength(final int maxLength) {
        mMaxLength = maxLength;
        mNumChars = maxLength;

        setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new InputFilter.LengthFilter(maxLength)});

        setText(null);
        invalidate();
}
```

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
PinEntryEditText.setMaxLength(5);
PinEntryEditText.setMaxLength(6);
PinEntryEditText.setMaxLength(7);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
int maxLength = 3;
editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{
    new InputFilter.LengthFilter(maxLength)});
```

This also working with it

```
InputFilter[] fa = new InputFilter[1];
fa[0]=new InputFilter.LengthFilter(8);editText.setFilters(fa)
```

Comment: It is not working .Whatever limit I set ,it shows 4 pins by default.

Comment: Might be it would not work in your case but the library you are using also used this approach.